# AngularJS Directive element method binding - TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'functionName' in 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

This is the controller of the main template:

```
app.controller('OverviewCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$routeParams', 'websiteService', 'helperService', function($scope, $location, $routeParams, websiteService, helperService) {
    ...     
    $scope.editWebsite = function(id) {
        $location.path('/websites/edit/' + id);
    };
}]);
```

This is the directive:

```
app.directive('wdaWebsitesOverview', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            heading: '=',
            websites: '=',
            editWebsite: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: 'views/websites-overview.html'
    }
});
```

This is how the directive is applied in main template:

```
<wda-websites-overview heading="'All websites'" websites="websites" edit-website="editWebsite(id)"></wda-websites-overview>
```

and this is method is called from directive template (website-overview.html):

```
<td data-ng-click="editWebsite(website.id)">EDIT</td>
```

QUESTION: When EDIT is clicked, this error appears in the console:

> TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'editWebsite' in 1

Does anyone know what goes on here?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Since you defined an expression binding (`&`), you need to explicitly call it with an object literal parameter containing `id` if you want to bind it in the HTML as `edit-website="editWebsite(id)"`.

Indeed, Angular needs to understand what this `id` is in your HTML, and since it is not part of your scope, you need to add what are called "locals" to your call by doing:

```
data-ng-click="editWebsite({id: website.id})"
```

Or as an alternative:

```
data-ng-click="onClick(website.id)"
```

With the controller/link code:

```
$scope.onClick = function(id) {
  // Ad "id" to the locals of "editWebsite" 
  $scope.editWebsite({id: id});
}
```

---

AngularJS includes an explanation of this in its documentation; look for the example involving `"close({message: 'closing for now'})"` at the following URL:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: @floribon I know this is kind of old, but do you have an example of typescripting the callback?

Comment: "_Often it's desirable to pass data from the isolate scope via an expression to the parent scope; **this can be done by passing a map of local variable names and values into the expression wrapper function**. For example, the `hideDialog` function takes a message to display when the dialog is hidden. This is specified in the directive by calling `close({message: 'closing for now'})`. Then the local variable `message` will be available within the `on-close` expression._" [emph mine] Truth is stranger than fiction. I'd like to know how they picked this as the best solution for event handlers.

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR;** - You are assuming that the bound function is being passed to the child component, as it would be in React. This is incorrect. In fact, AngularJS is parsing the string template and creating a new function, which then calls the parent function.

This generated function expects to receive an object with keys and values, rather than a plain variable.

### Longer Explanation

This happens when you have bound a function using '&', and have tried to call that function from your controller, passing a plain variable rather than an object containing the name of the plain variable.
The object keys are needed by the templating engine to work out how to pass values into the bound function.

eg. you have called `boundFunction('cats')` rather than `boundFunction({value: 'cats'})`

### Worked Example

Say I create a component like this:

```
const MyComponent = {
  bindings: {
    onSearch: '&'
  },
  controller: controller
};
```

This function (in the parent) looks like this:

```
onSearch(value) {
  // do search
}
```

In my parent template, I can now do this:

```
<my-component on-search="onSearch(value)"></my-component>
```

The binding here will be parsed from the string. **You're not actually passing the function. AngularJS is making a function for you which calls the function. The binding created in the template can contain lots of things other than the function call.**

AngularJS somehow needs to work out where to get `value` from, and it does this by receiving an object from the parent.

In myComponent controller, I need to do something like:

```
handleOnSearch(value) {
  if (this.onSearch) {
    this.onSearch({value: value})
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, someone thought this comment was superfluous, even though it'd been upvoted, so let me try again: **Note that the crux of this answer is:** "_you have called `boundFunction('cats')` rather than `boundFunction({value: 'cats'})`_"