# AngularJS Error: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '$ctrl' in

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the `directory` component passing a function to the `question` component. The `question` component is to take an input, and then update the `directory` component with this input via the function. When the `question` component tries to access this function, there is the JS error: `angular.min.js:123 TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '$ctrl' in Lee`. What am I doing incorrectly to trigger this error?

https://plnkr.co/edit/hXjhhJcCWPcavp8Z8BRa?p=preview

```
let directoryTemplate = 
  '<question on-click="$ctrl.updateLastName()"></question>' +
  '<br />' +
  'Full name: {{$ctrl.fullName}}';

class directoryController {
  constructor() {
    this.fullName;
    this.firstName = 'Jack';
  }
  updateLastName(lastName) {
    this.fullName = `${this.firstName} ${lastName}`;
  }
}


let questionTemplate = 
  '<input ng-model="$ctrl.input" />' +
  '<button ng-click="$ctrl.onClick($ctrl.input)">Submit</button>';

class questionController {
  constructor() {
    this.input;
  }
}


angular
  .module('app', [])
  .component('directory', {
    template: directoryTemplate,
    controller: directoryController
  })
  .component('question', {
    template: questionTemplate,
    controller: questionController,
    bindings: {
      onClick: '&'
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A similar question has been answered here: [AngularJS Directive element method binding - TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'functionName' in 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244358/angularjs-directive-element-method-binding-typeerror-cannot-use-in-operator)

In a nutshell, in your template calling the component, you need to pass the signature of your function (including the argument's name):

```
<question on-click="$ctrl.updateLastName(lastName)">
```

And in your component you need to call your function with a JSON containing the lastName:

```
<button ng-click="$ctrl.onClick({lastName: $ctrl.input})">
```

See the uploaded plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/iOA29KGEbl6NLubP1cvb?p=preview

By the way you should use ES6 template strings for your multiline templates, like you did for updateLastName method (see https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings).

Comment: Good call on the ES6 template string for my `directoryTemplate` variable. I have also updated my code so the `onClick` binding in the `question` component to use `<` instead of `&`. I am now getting the last name as undefined. What am I doing incorrectly? https://plnkr.co/edit/OE8kmUOQxOdec4D1cshe?p=preview

Comment: When using `<`, angular executes `$ctrl.updateLastName(lastName)`, but lastName is undefined. Whereas when using `&`, you tell angular you're passing a function signature and it wraps it into a function for later execution. See here for further explanation: http://blog.krawaller.se/posts/dissecting-bindings-in-angularjs/